# separate first character from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to separate the number which is the first character of a string from the rest of the string.
For example 1options to select should be 1 options to select.

Please note that the select list is dynamically generated

```
<select>
    <option>1options to select</option>
    <option>2anything can be here</option>
    <option>3anything can be here</option>
    <option>5anything can be here</option>
</select>

$(".custom-ordered-list select option").each(function() {

    //i think i need to loop through but not sure what to do next.                      
});
```

Comment: can be 9999option to select ? or '9999anything' ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it in the following way:

```
$(".custom-ordered-list select option").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/^\d+/, "$& ");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/63h7T/

Comment: This did the job perfectly.

Comment: @roasted Read the comments below the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".custom-ordered-list select option").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^(\d+)(.+)$/, '$1 $2'));
});
```